# How to Send File(pdf) from Local Computer to API Whatsapp (Chat-API)

Tags: php, whatsapp

Greatings,

Today i Want to Make some task to upload some pdf file using Chat-API whatsapp.
the task maybe I will Run on windows shell, but now I test it on PHP file.
I using the documentation like this

```
$to = 'myPhone';
$url = 'https://chat-apiurl?andtokenhere';
$imageLocation = 'http://localhost/chat-api/file.pdf';
$data = [
    'phone'=> $to,
    'body' =>$imageLocation,
    'filename'=>"filepdf.jpg",
    'caption'=>'test',
];
$send = json_encode($data);

$options = stream_context_create(['http' => [
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
        'content' => $send,
    ]
]);
// Send a request

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $options);
echo $result;
?>
```

if i change the file to online url that's work fine, but when using local file I got the error on result like that

`{"error":"Unsupported file type"}`

I Have try to convert my file to base 64 but that's return error like this
`{"sent":false,"message":"Message was not sent: empty body. Please provide message text in body parameter in JSON POST."}`

and that's the way i convert to base64

```
$getExtension = explode(".",$imageLocation);
$base64 = 'data:image/'.$getExtension[1].';base64,'.file_get_contents($imageLocation);
```

can anyone help me to send the local file? or maybe have other way to do that. or other API?

Thankyou so much

Comment: Yes I will help you

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was posted a long time ago, but I'll leave the answer in case anyone is looking for a solution.

```
$base64='data:image/'.$getExtension[1].';base64,'.file_get_contents($imageLocation);
```

for:

```
$base64='data:image/'.$getExtension[1].';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageLocation));
```